# On google docs...... how can I make the word * i * autocorrect to the uppercase

Tags: google-docs

If I am writing a novel for instance, what should I do to ease my writing because google docs preferences are not adjusting my works? So I don't waste time going back to edit or so I don't need to worry about the shift control.

Comment: Do a find / replace.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).